# Benefits of implementing 2FA on top of Active directory

Tags: active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

What is the benefit of implementing 2FA authentication layer over on premise Windows Active Directory authentication ? Moreover, what would be the problems that 2FA solve in a setup where everything is integrated with AD ?

Thanks

Comment: @GovindSharma-MSFT: Hi, it is not, the scope of the question was for on premise.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the post with ADFS so I assume you will use that to implement MFA (e.g. via Azure AD).

In a word, security.

Microsoft calculates that implementing MFA defeats 99.9% of [hacking attempts](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2019/08/20/one-simple-action-you-can-take-to-prevent-99-9-percent-of-account-attacks/).

Comment: By mistake. It is in scope of on premise